# Contact table: managing a new field

Tags: extension, database

in my extension I have the need to manage a new contact information (I added a field in civicrm_contact, instead of using a custom field).
Using the buildForm hook, I can show the input element in the contact form, but I don't know how to write the field value in the database.
Is there a specific hook for this operation?

Thanks
Marcello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hook or api specifically for writing to a field added to the civicrm_contact table, as that is a bad unsupported hack to core. I'd suggest changing your code to use the support provided for custom fields. That way you can be more confident that a code review of the extension won't end up preventing it from being published on civicrm.org for auto-distribution. If you still want to proceed with this bad pattern, then you might want to consider writing SQL and submitting it via db_query.

Comment: Thanks' Joe. At the end I have followed the way you suggest.

Comment: Great! FWIW, I'd appreciate having the answer marked as accepted and even upvoted ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the post hook on the Contact entity.